# Tkinter 1 line function as command

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I have 5 buttons in my program and all of them need to set a single variable.
I could make an separate function function for all of them but i thought there should be an better way to so.
So I tried the following:

```
 self.__Button1 = tk.Button(self.parent,text='Start', command=lambda: (start_flag = True)).pack()
```

But this doesnt work. Is there an way to do this or maybe other easy way to all set there own variable (start_flag is one of them)?

Thanks in regards

Update:

With novel's comment i tried the following:
But this doesnt work so i will just make 5 almost the same functions as furas suggested.

```
    def setarr(self, *args, flag, bool):
    # set flag according to button press
    print(flag)
    flag = bool
```

Comment: You could use `lambda: setattr(self, 'start_flag', True)`. Or better yet redesign your program with a subclassed Button that does whatever you need.

Comment: create separated functions - it will be more readable for you and others.

Comment: setattr is a built in function, you don't need to define it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way to do this is to create a function that takes a single argument, and sets the variable based on a passed-in parameter. You can use either `lambda` or `functools.partial` to create the button command:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.variable = None
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.root, text="One",
                                 command=lambda: self.set_variable(1))
        self.button2 = tk.Button(self.root, text="Two", 
                                 command=lambda: self.set_variable(2))
        self.label = tk.Label(self.root, text="", width=20)

        self.label.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.button1.pack(side="top")
        self.button2.pack(side="top")

    def start(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

    def set_variable(self, value):
        self.variable = value
        self.label.configure(text="variable = %s" % self.variable)

example = Example()
example.start()
```